# include hash # in url with httplib2

Tags: python, httplib2

I'm trying to make an http request using httplib2:

```
import httplib2, time, re, urllib`
conn = httplib2.Http(".cache")


page = conn.request(u"http://www.mydomain.com/search?q=cars#p=100","GET")
```

The response is ok, but the "#p=100" does not get passed over.  Does anyone know how to pass this over with httplib2?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fragment in the URL is not passed to the server.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to Ignacio because he answered correctly first.
The relevant documentation, from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-4.1

> When a URI reference is used to perform a retrieval action on the identified resource, the optional fragment identifier, separated from the URI by a crosshatch ("#") character, consists of additional reference information to be interpreted by the user agent after the retrieval action has been successfully completed.  **As such, it is not part of a URI**, but is often used in conjunction with a URI.

In the case of the link above, the browser uses the information after the crosshatch as a bookmark for a particular spot in the HTML.

Comment: thanks adam and ignacio, is there anyway i can programmatically use the crosshatch in python/django?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else stumbles onto this question and wants an answer, I found an answer from another [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11968983/1628212):

> The fragment of the url after the hash (#) symbol is for client-side handling and isn't actually sent to the webserver. My guess is there is some javascript on the page that requests the correct data from the server using AJAX, and you need to figure out what URL is used for that.
>
> If you use chrome you can watch the Network tab of the developer tools and see what URLs are requested when you click the link to go to page two in your browser.

To get the developer tools In Chrome press F11(Windows) or Apple+Alt+i(Mac). If you click on the option's gear in the bottom right corner, make sure the `Preserve log upon navigation` is checked.