# urllib2 not retrieving url with hashes on it

Tags: python

I'm trying to get some data from a webpage, but I found a problem. Whenever I want to go to the next page (i.e. page 2) to keep retrieving the data on it, I keep receiving the data from page 1. Apparently something goes wrong trying to switch to the next page.

The thing is, I haven't had problems with urls like this:

```
'http://www.webpage.com/index.php?page=' + str(pageno)
```

I can just start a while statement and I'll just jump to page 2 by adding 1 to "pageno"

My problem comes in when I try to open an url with this format:

```
'http://www.webpage.com/search/?show_all=1#sort_order=ASC&page=' + str(pageno)
```

As

```
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.webpage.com/search/?show_all=1#sort_order=ASC&page=4').read()
```

will retrieve the source code from http://www.webpage.com/search/?show_all=1

There is no other way to retrieve other pages without using the hash, as far as I'm concerned.

I guess it's just urllib2 ignoring the hash, as it is normally used to specify a starting point for a browser.

Comment: Having a query string after the # mark is nonsense - this is never ever a valid URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fragment of the url after the hash (#) symbol is for client-side handling and isn't actually sent to the webserver.  My guess is there is some javascript on the page that requests the correct data from the server using AJAX, and you need to figure out what URL is used for that.

If you use chrome you can watch the Network tab of the developer tools and see what URLs are requested when you click the link to go to page two in your browser.

Comment: That was exactly it. I didn't know about the network tab on Chrome. As soon as I clicked on page 2 I got the URL I needed. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

that's because hash are not part of the url that is sent to the server, it's a fragment identifier that is used to identify elements inside the page. Some websites misused the hash fragment for JavaScript hook for identifying pages though. You'll either need to be able to execute the JavaScript on the page or you'll need to reverse engineer the JavaScript and emulate the true search request that is being made, presumably through ajax. Firebug's Net tab will be really useful for this.